# jquery cycle + responsive design - absolute item

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a site that has some 'ad blocks' which advertise various aspects of the site. My site is setup with the Skeleton framework so that it is responsive. The one adblock I have is just two images that rotate between each each other...and it works create and resizes appropriately as the screen sizes rotates.

I have another ad block which is a div with a background image, and then there is a specific part of it (middle) which has images that rotate (using jquery cycle plugin). I have the image portion absolutely positioned so that that I can have it display where I want and only that aspect rotate through the images. The background image part resizes appropriately, however my images do not...they stay the same size and therefore break outside of the background image that I have it 'framed' within.

I mocked up a quick fiddle of whats happening:
http://jsfiddle.net/DjvS9/1/

Note that instead of the background image that frames it, I just put a div with some text.

Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong, and what I need to fix? Is it because of the absolute positioning..??

The premise I used to fix it for the 1st ad block that worked was the example I found in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vengiss/QRWAD/6/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

Html code:

```
<div id="bkgd">
<div id="MyAdBlock">
text<br />        
    text<br />
text<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

<div id="MyAds" class="MyAdImg">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/165x197" width="165" class="placeholder1" />
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://placekitten.com/165/197" class="image_size" alt="Img1" /></a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://placekitten.com/165/194" class="image_size" alt="Img2" /></a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://placekitten.com/165/195" class="image_size" alt="Img3" /></a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://placekitten.com/165/196" class="image_size" alt="Img4" /></a>
</div>
```

CSS:
    body{
     background:#000;
    }

```
#bkgd{

}

#MyAdBlock{
position:relative;
background:#ffffff;  
max-width:50%;
height:auto;
border:5px solid red;
}

.MyAdImg{
position:absolute;
top:73px;
left:28px;
}

 .image_size{
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
 }
```